# Recommend Deletion in Low Quality Posts (answers) review queue: Give a form comment for "Don't post a link to a duplicate question"

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4916983), for example, shouldn't exist. Instead. it should be flagged, or, with sufficient rep, voted to be closed. Can we get a reason like this:

> Instead of posting a link to another question on [Site Name], please
>   close this question as a
>   [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) instead.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se.  Asking for form comments form SE is a slippery slope, and there's evidence that such comments are often abused.